# php-fpmエラーについて

Tags: php, nginx

**環境**
・Nginx
・php-fpm

---

**特定Webページで下記表示になります**

> An error occurred.

---

**/var/log/nginx/error.log**

> [error] 15753#15753: *8597 upstream prematurely closed FastCGI stdout
>   while reading response header from upstream, client: IPアドレス, server:
>   ドメイン, request: "GET /url HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "ホスト名", referrer:
>   "http://url"
>
> [error] 15753#15753: *8597 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP
>   Notice:  Undefined variable: hoge

---

**Q1**
・hoge変数未定義のNoticeが原因みたいですが、これが原因でエラーになるのでしょうか？
・Noticeエラーで画面表示されなくなるのは、php-fpmの仕様ですか？

---

**Q2**
・php-fpmエラーをWeb画面表示するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？
・nginx/error.logをその都度確認していくのが大変なので